# Slack: Count number of messages per day/week

Tags: slack, slack-api

TL;DR; How to summarize the number of messages in a slack channel every day with a regex/user.

I am using slack and love it! One of the most important channels in my team is the alert channel. We post alerts from our services/3rd parties to the channel and that keeps us updated if anything goes wrong.

We were wondering if there is a way to post a summary of all messages with a regex every day/week/month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one approach that works.

- You need a Slack app that runs once a day to query your channel and post
  the message with the summary.
- Use the API method [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) in your app to
  retrieve all message from a channel and count them to create the summary. You can specify a timeframe for that method, so you only need to retrieve the messages from one day.
- Use the API method [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to post the summary to the
  Slack channel.

Comment: My requirement is very similar where would need to collect #messages on a public slack channel(I am not owner) for past one year. How can I get this done ?

Comment: @B_B Same approach. Or you can check out this answer for a tool that does it for you: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130485/how-to-export-slack-conversation-thread-without-admin-account/132521#132521